# Получить скорость текущего подключения интернет-канала

Tags: delphi, winapi

Если открыть в панели управления windows *текущие подключения*, нажать правой кнопкой мыши на активное подключение и кликнуть на пункт *состояние*, то можно увидеть следующие окно:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как мне получить то значение, которое обведено красным маркером на скриншоте ?

Функцию проверки на текущее подключение уже нашел (не знаю как сюда вставить код), осталось дело за малым - узнать максимальную скорость.

Comment: Добрый день! А что вы подразумеваете под максимальной скоростью? Текущая максимальная скорость скачивания с определённого сайта? Или максимальная для вашей сетевой карты? Или ещё какая-то?

Comment: @Deft вон же красным обведено. Если вы намекаете на что-то другое, или придираетесь к словам, то будьте конкретнее и детальнее плиз ;-)

Comment: Чтобы вставить код - нужно вставить его текстом, потом выделить и нажать Ctrl-K или кнопку `{}` в редакторе.

Comment: @Kromster Если вам нужно то, что обведено жирно-красным, то почитайте [тут](http://www.delphimaster.ru/articles/netmon/). Раздел "Определение входящего и исходящего трафика".

Comment: @Deft мне - не нужно. Мне был неясен ваш комментарий, я попросил уточнить. Всё )

Comment: @Deft Спасибо, но при использовании способа выдает ошибку  Undeclared identifier: 'TMibIfArray'.
Понимаю что нужно что то подключить в uses, но что конкретно ? На странице нету упоминаний об этом

Comment: @Deft Разобрался, огромное спасибо !

Comment: Можно использовать WMI, чтобы получить сведения о скоростях подключений сетевых интерфейсов с помощью запроса: Select CurrentBandWidth from Win32_PerfFormattedData_Tcpip_NetworkInterface